# inversifyJs error: Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: String

Tags: javascript, inversifyjs

In mine application using inversify for DI conteinerisation

have a abstract class

```
@injectable()
export abstract class Name {
  tableName: string;

  constructor(
    @inject("DatabaseService") public db: DatabaseService,
    @inject("GenesisApiService") public api: GenesisApiService
  ) {}

  abstract fullSync(accountId: number): Promise<void>;

  abstract incrementalSync(accountId: number): Promise<void>;
}
```

also have class which one extends this Abstract class

```
@injectable()
export class ServiceName extends Name {
  tableName = "Name";

  constructor(
    @inject("ServiceName") db: ServiceName,
    @inject("Service2Name") api: Service2Name
  ) {
    super(ServiceName, Service2Name);
  }

  async fullSync(accountId: number): Promise<void> {
    const apiUrl = "/servlet/rs/v1/schedule/fetch/incrementalSync?authToken=";
    const result = await this.api.get(apiUrl);
    console.log("result", result);
  }

  async incrementalSync(accountId: number): Promise<void> {
    return null;
  }
}
```

after im containerized like in documentations

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container } from "inversify";
import { ServiceName } from "./services/ServiceName/ServiceName";

export const container = new Container({
  autoBindInjectable: true,
  skipBaseClassChecks: true,
});

container.bind<ServiceName>("ServiceName").to(ServiceName);
```

after tryng to invoke service methods

```
import { container } from "../ioc";
import { GenesisApiService } from "../services/genesis-api";

export const ServiceName = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@1");
    const service = container.get<ServiceName>("ServiceName");
    await service.get("123321");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

ServiceName();
```

and getting this error

```
Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: String
```